# JOINing 3 tables with ORDER, LIMIT and WHERE

Tags: postgresql, join

I am trying to join these 3 tables by key `organization_id` but I had no success.
What I'm trying to achieve: I know `ipo` and I want to get some values from name_entries and address_entries.
First query gives me `organization_id`, which is used in second and third query.
Is this even possible in 1 query?

My current solution is calling these queries separately and then joining them in my code.

```
SELECT * FROM "rpo"."organization_identifier_entries" WHERE ipo = '********' ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM "rpo"."organization_address_entries" WHERE organization_id='########' ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT * FROM "rpo"."organization_name_entries" WHERE organization_id='########'  ORDER BY effective_to DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Are any of these unique? like ipo or organization ID on any of these tables?

Comment: No, they aren't - that's why I have the ORDERs and LIMITs in place.

Comment: what a horrible schema. You don't have any PRIMARY KEYS on any of these tables?

Comment: All of them have "id". You helped me with my first question - now I'm processing data from the dump.

Comment: ah. that's you =) You should punch them in the face, with love. Can't be your fault if it's someone else's data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`

I think what you want is something like,

```
SELECT *
FROM rpo.organization_identifier_entries
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM rpo.organization_address_entries
  ORDER BY updated_at DESC
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS oae
  USING (organization_id)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT *
  FROM rpo.organization_name_entries
  ORDER BY effective_to DESC NULLS FIRST
  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
) AS one
  USING (organization_id)
WHERE ipo = '********'
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Oh, and btw, never double-quote things in PostgreSQL unless you want to enable a very stupid capability to make identifiers caps-sensitive. This is a **bad** idea, unless that third party is also doing it and they have capital letters in their identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not work - using this I was only able to fetch organization_id and ipo from 1st table, everything else is NULL and Sqlectron says: "Duplicated columns: id, effective_from, effective_to, created_at, updated_at. It may cause the result in the second column overwriting the first one. Use an alias to avoid it." I tried specifying columns - I got rid of the duplicates error, but every other column was NULL.

Comment: If the columns are null that means there is not a single row for that organization_id

Comment: That's weird - when I select the rows manually, I am able to find it.

Comment: On the rows returned from this query with null, are you looking at the same organizatoin_id or are you looking on the basis of the IPO? And are you looking at the first row return with that sorting criterea (ie, is it finding something which is mostly null)

Comment: I don't really understand the question - I just replaced ******* with real IPO.

Comment: You have two other queries there, the question is on them -- are they returning NULL's in first row returned with that IPO and those ORDER BY clauses? or are they returning 0-rows?